# Hibernate Mapping - Converting XML to Annotation - Wrong Column name being generated

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a two projects in hibernate one is for XML and one is for annotation.
My XML Mapping config works fine with composite keys while the annotation style generates a wrong column.

Annotation Style Generates this table

```
Hibernate: create table agent (agent_id number(10,0) not null, start_dttm    timestamp not null, agent_cd varchar2(255 char), end_dttm timestamp, primary key (agent_id, start_dttm))
Hibernate: create table agent_license (agent_license_id number(10,0) not null, agent_agent_id number(10,0), agent_start_dttm timestamp, agent_id number(10,0), primary key (agent_license_id))
Hibernate: alter table agent_license add constraint FKncan0jjmt1siq0a6a19ll978m foreign key (agent_agent_id, agent_start_dttm) references agent
Hibernate: alter table agent_license add constraint FKp64d6078jnxi3hq0n0es0yhs foreign key (agent_id, agent_start_dttm) references agent
```

a redundant column for AgentLicense with agent_agent_id instead of agent_id only.

This is Working Correctly XML Config
XML generates
Agent Table with column agent_id,start_dttm,agent_cd
Agent_License with column agent_id,agent_start_dttm

Agent Model

```
<class name="com.poc.model.Agent" table="AGENT">
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.poc.model.pk.AgentPK">
        <key-property name="agentId" type="long">
            <column name="AGENT_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="startDateTime" type="timestamp">
            <column name="START_DTTM" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="agentCode" type="string">
        <column name="AGENT_CD" length="20" />
    </property>
    <set name="agentLicenses" table="AGENT_LICENSE" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="AGENT_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
            <column name="AGENT_START_DTTM" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.poc.model.AgentLicense" />
    </set>
</class>
```

AgentLicense Model

```
<class name="com.poc.model.AgentLicense" table="AGENT_LICENSE">
    <id name="agentLicenseId" type="long">
        <column name="AGENT_LICENSE_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="agent" class="com.poc.model.Agent" fetch="select">
        <column name="AGENT_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
        <column name="AGENT_START_DTTM" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="licenseNum" type="string">
        <column name="LICENSE_NUM" length="40" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Agent PK Model

```
<class name="com.poc.model.Agent" table="AGENT">
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.poc.model.pk.AgentPK">
        <key-property name="agentId" type="long">
            <column name="AGENT_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="startDateTime" type="timestamp">
            <column name="START_DTTM" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="agentCode" type="string">
        <column name="AGENT_CD" length="20" />
    </property>
    <set name="agentLicenses" table="AGENT_LICENSE" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="AGENT_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
            <column name="AGENT_START_DTTM" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.poc.model.AgentLicense" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Correct Annotation is this

```
Result table generation
Agent Table with column agent_id,start_dttm,agent_cd
Agent_License with column agent_id,agent_start_dttm

public class Agent {
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "agentId", column = @Column(name = "AGENT_ID", nullable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "startDateTime", column = @Column(name = "START_DTTM", nullable = false)) })
private AgentPK agentPK;
@Column(name="AGENT_CODE")
private String agentCode;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "agent")
private Set<AgentLicense> agentLicenses = new HashSet<AgentLicense>();
}

public class AgentLicense {
@Id
@Column(name = "AGENT_LICENSE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long agentLicenseId;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "AGENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "AGENT_ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "AGENT_START_DTTM", referencedColumnName = "START_DTTM") })
private Agent agent;
}

@Embeddable
public class AgentPK implements Serializable{
@Column(name = "AGENT_ID", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
private long agentId;
@Column(name = "START_DTTM", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startDateTime;
//HashCode and equals here
}
```

Correct Full answer

Comment: Didnt exactly get your question...

Comment: updated the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your inverse mapping for `AgentLicense` in `Agent`

```
public class Agent {
  // ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agent")
  @JoinColumns( ... )
  private Set<AgentLicense> agentLicenses;
}
```